# Print number mapping to documents instead of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, graph, hashmap

I have two collections `Node` and `Edge`.

In `Edge` I have two fields `source` and `target` storing the ids of the nodes from and to which they are linked.

The ids of the nodes (both stored i `node.id`, `edge.source` and `edge.target`) are not very readable, so what I want to do is to print the set of nodes and the set of edges but instead of printing their ids, I want to print an index starting from 1.

So if I have 3 nodes, my result should be

> Set of nodes = {n1, n2, n3}

and if I have two edges where the first is linked between n1 and n2 and the second is linked between n2 and n3, I want to output

> Set of edges = {e1 = (n1, n2), e2 = (n2, n3)}

If I didn't care about changing the ids to some more readable indices, I could print the edges with

```
edges = edges.map((edge, index) => 'e' + (index + 1) + ' = (' + edge.source + ', ' + edge.target + ')');
console.log('Set of edges = {' + edges.join(', ') + '}');
```

and the nodes with

```
nodes = nodes.map((node, index) => 'n' + (index + 1));
console.log('Set of nodes = {' + nodes.join(', ') + '}');
```

My guess is that I have to create a hash mapping of the nodes before printing the edges, so I am sure each edge's source-id and target-id will be translated into the correct node number/index.

## Edit

The nodes and edges are very simple

```
const nodeSchema = new Schema({});
const edgeSchema = new Schema({ source: Schema.Types.ObjectId, target: Schema.Types.ObjectId});
```

So they don't hold any other information than the automatically created `_id` and the edges hold references to the nodes using the nodes' `_id` value.

Comment: Can you include example of `Node` and `Edges` at Question?

Comment: _"Hope it is sufficient "_ Can you provide adequate text of `Node` and `Edges` at Question  to produce expected result `{e1 = (n1, n2), e2 = (n2, n3)}`? And share what you have tried to resolve issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works

```
const hashmap = {};

nodes.map((node, idx) => {
  hashmap[node.id] = 'n' + (idx + 1);
});

nodes = Object.keys(hashmap).map(key => hashmap[key]);
edges = edges.map((edge, idx) => 'e' + (idx + 1) + '=(' + hashmap[edge.source] + ', ' + hashmap[edge.target] + ')');
```